# how can i abort request from a stream without losing data?(node.js)

Tags: node.js, stream, request, pipe

I want to record a IP camera video, i have record and stop record button.
I can record the video when i press the record button.
But i don't know how to stop the request when i press the stop record.
I use the request.abort(). It can stop the request, but also drop my data which was downloaded.
IP camera is on http://192.168.0.55:8080

```
filename = './video1.ogg';
file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
if(req.body.record == 1) //recording
{
    theRequest = request('http://192.168.0.55:8080/');
    theRequest.pipe(file);
}
else if(req.body.record == 0) //stop recording
{
    theRequest.abort();
}
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(req.body.record == 0) //stop recording
{
    theRequest.pause();//add pause will solve this problem
    theRequest.abort();
}
```